# Get current language from database before resume Angular app

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

So, I need help... I dont know how to do this...

I have an angular app that is using "sails" to work with sockets. I'm using "$sails" service.

Before the app start, After socket is connected, I want to call my rest services using socket to get current logged user languages. I need the "locale" to start "angular-translate" and load static file with translations.

Do U Know how can I do this?

Comment: create a service for it and out it in your module run block

Comment: Can U give me more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wouldn't need to input to database for translation use
because you can try to use local storage translation for get the current language

```
$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
```

then on your UI do this on your script (correct me if im wrong or either there's another angular solution on this one)

```
localStorage.getItem('NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY')
```

but before you do that, you need to install their plugin
try to find angular translate local storage
or do this on your command prompt

```
$ bower install angular-translate-storage-local //if you are using bower
$ npm install angular-translate-storage-local // if you are using npm
```

hope it's working :)

Comment: I dont know when the user will clear the cache... So the `$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();` is not a good way :'(

Comment: thanks for the scenario information anyway, as I know the cache clearing should not affect the translation finding
because it's saved on local storage not on cache storage. unless user is going to clear it from the local storage directly . but still it will be back too with previous language settings

Comment: But I just want to get the current language from user database and later, load the json with the correct language...